# Notification for SES email verification status change

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses, moonmail

Is there a possibility to be notified by SNS (let's say to a HTTP(S) endpoint) whenever an Email Address verification status change happens?

So I wouldn't have to poll all email addresses in my account?

Comment: Red flag: you shouldn't be verifying email addresses often enough that this matters.  What is the circumstance that requires this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Michael - sqlbot is right, I did over-engineer it at first

I solved this by only polling the required email addresses (not all of my AWS account) if they haven't been updated for a while. This reduced the amount of transferred data.
So basically it just synchronizes the state of SES verification with the state in the application's database (where more info is held than just the status...)